# Windows service timer multithread

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I am building a Windows Service that will audit users based on a schedule in a database.  The service checks the database for scheduled audits every ten minutes.  Once and audit is started, it marks a start time in the database table so it will not start again if it takes longer than ten minutes.

My question is, is the following code acceptable for what I am doing and should I use multithreading every time 10 minutes is elapsed and if so, how would I accomplish this?

My sample code:

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    var aTimer = new Timer(600000);
    aTimer.Elapsed += ATimerElapsed;
    aTimer.Interval = 600000;
    aTimer.Enabled = true;
    GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
}

private static void ATimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
         Worker.ProcessScheduledAudits();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
         EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }                
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A System.Threading.Timer will use a thread from the Threadpool to run the Elapsed handler(s). So, you're already using multithreading just by using the timer. In fact, ALL timers use a background thread of some kind; they just differ on how they multithread in order to do what makes the most sense for the intended usage.

If you need to run something once every ten minutes, but also make sure that two handlers are never running at the same time, try setting a "CurrentlyRunning" flag in the Elapsed method, and examining it before doing any heavy lifting.

```
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        var aTimer = new Timer(600000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += ATimerElapsed;
        aTimer.Interval = 600000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        GC.KeepAlive(aTimer);
    }

    private static currentlyRunning;

    private static void ATimerElapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(currentlyRunning) return;
        currentlyRunning = true;
        try
        {
            Worker.ProcessScheduledAudits();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", ex.Message, EventLogEntryType.Error);
        }
        currentlyRunning = false;
    }
```

Theoretically, this could race, but as you're only kicking off a thread for this event every 10 minutes the odds are EXTREMELY unlikely.

Comment: What do you mean by race? I like this solution by the way.

Comment: By "race" I mean that two threads running this method at nearly the same time could both examine currentlyRunning and see it is false before one of them gets a chance to set it to true. The two threads will then proceed into the meat of the method in parallel, which is what you don't want. These types of bugs in multi-user or multi-threaded systems are generally known as "race conditions". However, because you're using a Timer which will only kick off this method once every ten minutes, you shouldn't have to worry about that unless you call this method using any other mechanism than the timer.

Answer (score 1):

This code already **is** "using multithreading". Assuming that your `Timer` instance is `System.Timers.Timer`, your `Elapsed` handler will run on a thread pool thread.

If this isn't what you want, you can use the `SynchronizingObject` property to modify the dispatch behavior. For more details, read [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification of the timer instance.